# Looping through table rows

Tags: jquery, html-table, rows

I want to loop through my table rows but I always have an error (unrecognized expression).
The error appears when the each function is called.

How can I fix this ?

Thanks in advance

Here's my code :

jQuery

```
$("#searchValue").keyup(function() {

            var table = $(this).siblings('table').not(':hidden');
            $(table +" tr").each(function() {

            });   
});
```

HTML

```
<table id='tablePlanning' class='tablesorter'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>PR Code</th>
            <th>Klant</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Project status</th>
            <th>Project Leader</th>
            <th>Coordinator</th>
            <th>Account manager</th>
            <th>Billing</th>
            <th>Start Datum</th>
            <th>Hardware</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>

<table id='tableProject' class='tablesorter'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Project ID</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Max Hours</th>
            <th>Achieved</th>
            <th>Difference</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$(table +" tr")` will take the jQuery object referenced by `table`, convert it to a string (`"[object Object]"`), append `" tr"` to it, and then try to use the resulting string `"[object Object] tr"` as a selector.

You probably wanted [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find), which is a function available on jQuery objects that searches for descendant elements within the elements in that jQuery object:

```
table.find('tr').each(/*...*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not looping through visible tables.

Loop through visible tables and inside each table, loop through rows.

Try:

```
$("#searchValue").keyup(function() {
    $("table:visible").each(function() {
        $(this).find("tr").each(function(){
            //do something
        });
    });   
});
```

Comment: Code-only answers are rarely good answers. Explain what's going on, what the user did wrong, how you changed it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

$("#searchValue").keyup(function() {

```
  $('tr:visible','table.tablesorter:visible').each(function(){
     var trObj=$(this);
     //-- your code goes here
  });
```

});

Explanation for selector used:
Select all visible tr under all visible table which is having class as "tablesorter".
& $(this) will refer to each tr object.